# Where is the text data stored during typing text in insert mode?

Tags: neovim, insert-mode, lua

I would like to develop a small app in React and Nodejs that sends real-time typed text from my Nodejs/Express server to my React frontend. To do this, I would like to use socket.io.

The text data is probably stored in memory when I type in insert mode. Does anyone know how I can retrieve this data?

I would use the Vim event CusorHoldI to trigger a function to make an HTTP request to my server.

(Are there neovim Lua plugins that can make HTTP requests)?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The most recently inserted text is in the `.` register (`:help quote.`).

You can also retrieve buffer contents with various functions like `getline()`.

Finally, you can handle typed content specially using a `:help prompt-buffer`.